# Cell not showing image after loaded from Firebase Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionviewcell, firebase-storage

I have a UITableViewCell which shows either an image or text. I have set my UIImageView height and width to <= 150 so that it wouldn't affect the cell height in case the image isn't present but the text is. (this is a messaging app)

Now my problem is, the cell does not show the image after it's loaded and user needs to go back, and view this screen again in order to see the image. How should i solve this?

**Before Image is loaded:**

[image]

**After the image is successfully loaded:**

[image]

as u can see, it doesnt show, only the view was expanded

**If user presses on BACK and comes again in this view,**

[image]

the image now shows.

how should i solve this issue? because I am not able to write `tableview.reloaddata()` in tableviewcell.

for my code in my tableviewcell to configure my cell:

```
func configCell(message: Message) {

    self.message = message

    if message.fromId == currentUser {

        sentView.isHidden = false

        sentMsgLabel.text = message.textMessages

        receivedMsgLabel.text = ""

        receivedView.isHidden = true

        timeReceived.text = ""

        timeSent.text = message.timestamp

        youLabel.text = "You"

        themLabel.text = ""


        if let ImageUrl = message.imageUrlLink {

            self.receivedimg.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(ImageUrl)
        }
        }

        else {

        sentView.isHidden = true

        sentMsgLabel.text = ""

        receivedMsgLabel.text = message.textMessages

        receivedMsgLabel.isHidden = false

        timeReceived.text = message.timestamp

        timeSent.text = ""

        // setting name for receipient
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(message.fromId!).child("name").observe(.value) { (datasnapshot) in
        if let name = datasnapshot.value as? String {
                self.themLabel.text = name
            }
        }

        youLabel.text = ""
    }
}
```

for my loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString code would be an extension as below:

```
let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

    extension UIImageView {

    func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(_ urlString: String) {

        self.image = nil

        //check cache for image first
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }

        //otherwise fire off a new download
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in

            //download hit an error so lets return out
            if error != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)

                    self.image = downloadedImage
                }
            })

        }).resume()
    }

}
```

Comment: Provide your code, let us see how you update the ImageView once the image is loaded

Comment: is `loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString` a custom function you made ?

Comment: yup, its a function that saves my image as cache so user doesnt need to load it everytime they open the view

Comment: But does it download the actual image on the first call ?

Comment: yes, it will download. My image were downloaded but it doesnt show up automatically unless i click back, and comes back to the view

Comment: Im pretty sure its from this function then, can you paste the code of `loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString` ? Maybe you forget to update the image when it's downloaded, but only do it when you come back and retrieve the image from cache

Comment: Thanks. Try putting a breakpoint on the self.image = ... within the main async ? Doest it go through ?

Comment: yes it does go through

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171743/discussion-between-frenchfalcon-and-william-loke).

Comment: try using `https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage` image downloader library. It automatically manages cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried so many ways, in the end..In my ViewDidload, I just added a delay

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Delay is required. Without it, it doesn't works. I am assuming it's due to the cell heights were set up and loaded before the image is finished loading, so the tablecell didn't know how much height was needed, that is why we need to reload the tableview after 1 second delay

Answer (score 1):

Your problem clearly after downloading image, your cell is not updated right the time, try **self.setNeedDisplays()** inside your cell. It tell your cell should update in next view cycle.

Instead of loading and catching yourself, I recommend using KingFisher framework, it do almost everything we need on working with image from remote server: downloading, catching, prefetching ... and **show your image immediately after downloading**

Comment: i added self.setNeedDisplay in my cell but it didnt had any effect. Will try look into KingFisher framework

Comment: setNeedDisplay: the view is not actually redrawn until the next drawing cycle, at which point all invalidated views are updated. So your are probably unlucky when your view still stay at the current cycle.

Comment: any other reference you can recommend? Kingfisher didnt work. I think is due to my tableview height is loaded and set before the image was loaded, therefore the image was hidden

Comment: Oh it is regular problem for any iOS developer, method heightForCellAtIndex always called before cellForRowOfIndex. Many way to face this problems. The easiest way is store your tableView as a property in your cell, then call tableView.reloadCellAtIndexPath. A better way is implementing a static function in your cell class, try to calculate your cell height, return it inside heightForRowAtIndex, cache them if you want.

Comment: what would be your suggestion to face this problem?

Comment: As I commented, you can tell tableView reload cell manually after image loaded

Comment: 1/ self.superView.reloadRowsAtIndexPath (inside your cell class)

Comment: 2/ Or store a reference to parent tableView as a property, achieving that inside cellForRowAtIndexPath: cell.tableView = self.tableView

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing action into the `UITableViewCell` do action inside `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //Your actuions here
}
```

Then you can use `tableView.reloadData()` inside your `UITableViewController`

Hope this will help to solve your problem.

Comment: I guess the OP calls the configCell function from the cellForRowAt ?
So it should work

Comment: So i call the configCell function from cellForRowAt? meaning i'll need to redo the code to and put it under cellfORowAt?

Comment: Yes, if you put configureCell function inside cellForRowAt means everytime when we call tableView.reloadData() that will called configureCell function everytime

Comment: it's already there, and if i were to tableview.reloaddata, my whole message will be cleared

Comment: tableView.reloadData() is only to reload tableView with current content how that clear data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that this code is being executed once but your UITableView is still loading the cell anyway as the count is clearly 2. When you pass in your Message object to your `UICollectionViewCell` class inside of your `cellForRowAt indexPath` method, you'll want to use a `didSet` on that message and THEN call your function. This means that every time a message is passed in and when it is passed in, whatever is inside the didSet will be executed.

*Inside your UICollectionViewCell class:*

```
var message: Message? {
    didSet {
        configCell(message)
    }
}
```

*Class with your UITableViewController:*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = // your cell here dequeue cell and downcast as your cell class e.g as! MyCell

    cell.message = yourMessagesArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I resolved it.

Inside your *ViewController* create a function that will **update each cell** dynamically:

```
private func reloadRowAt(_ indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadRows( at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Now use it inside *cellForRowAtindexPath()* use it:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MyCustomCell else { return UITableViewCell()}

   // Download and refresh cell
   let image = imageDownloader.loadImage(from: url) {
       self.reloadRowAt(indexPath) 
   }
   cell.image = image
   return cell
  }
```

Now look in the code this `{ self.reloadRowAt(indexPath) }`, this is a completion handler of the method that downloads the image, once the image is downloaded it returns to the cell.

```
func loadImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping () -> Void ) -> UIImage {
    let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 140)
    // Download and Compress image to fit container size
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
      guard let newimage = self.downloadAndCompress(url: url, newSize: size) else { return }
      // Show in UI
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion()
      }
    }
    return UIImage()
  }
```

In addition, I compressed the downloaded image into a new size with the method `self.downloadAndCompress`.

See full code:

https://gist.github.com/richimf/fad8d320fbfb5059c5472e0f55ea24c2